# Can a differential operator have infinite deficiency indices?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

Suppose $T$ is a differential operator of order $m$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, that is:
$$
  \big(Tf\big)(x) =
  \sum_{k \, \leq \, m} \alpha_k(x) \, f^{(k)}(x)
  \quad \text{ for all } \quad
  f \in \mathrm{D}(T) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R})
  \: .
$$
Deficiency indices $n_+$ and $n_-$ are defined as follows:
$$
  n_\pm = \dim \ker (T^* \pm \mathrm{i} I) \: .
$$
**Is is possible for $n_\pm$ to be infinite?** And if the aswer is yes, what conditions have to be satisfied in order for $n_\pm < \infty$?

---

From the definition of the nulity indices, they should be equal to the number of independent solutions of the equation
$$
  T^* f(x) = \pm \mathrm{i} \, f(x) \: ,
$$
which is an ODE of order $m$. Therefore $n_\pm$ should be less or equal to $m$, is that right?